# CSS sticky positioning forcing scroll to the top after page load

Tags: css

I'm experiencing an odd issue with the sticky positioning feature that's interfering with the scroll positioning.

My intention is fairly common: keep an advertisement in a sidebar always visible when the visitor scrolls the page.

It does work as per definition as you can see in the code below — or in [the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uk4j8ejb/embedded/#result) if you prefer:

```css
body {
  margin: 6rem;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.sidebar .ads {
    position: sticky;
    top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <section class="col-md-10 listing">

          

          <div class="row">

              

            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="card-deck">

                <div class="card" data-mh="card">
                
                  <a href="">
                    <img class="card-img-top thumbnail" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/63b7/f/2013/041/9/d/free_youtube_thumbnail_template_by_imaura-d5ugja7.png" alt="Thumbnail" />
                  </a>
                  
                  
                  <div class="card-block">
                    
                    <h3 class="card-title d-flex align-items-center hidden-sm-down lang-en">
                      Title
                    </h3>
                    Et aliquip non culpa pariatur quis et consectetur dolor eu laborum in nisi voluptate ut commodo dolore dolore anim est et in eu voluptate velit nulla nisi occaecat anim ut.
                    
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
                  
              </div>
                  
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="card-deck">

                <div class="card" data-mh="card">
                
                  <a href="">
                    <img class="card-img-top thumbnail" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/63b7/f/2013/041/9/d/free_youtube_thumbnail_template_by_imaura-d5ugja7.png" alt="Thumbnail" />
                  </a>
                  
                  
                  <div class="card-block">
                    
                    <h3 class="card-title d-flex align-items-center hidden-sm-down lang-en">
                      Title
                    </h3>
                    Et aliquip non culpa pariatur quis et consectetur dolor eu laborum in nisi voluptate ut commodo dolore dolore anim est et in eu voluptate velit nulla nisi occaecat anim ut.
                    
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
                  
              </div>
                  
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="card-deck">

                <div class="card" data-mh="card">
                
                  <a href="">
                    <img class="card-img-top thumbnail" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/63b7/f/2013/041/9/d/free_youtube_thumbnail_template_by_imaura-d5ugja7.png" alt="Thumbnail" />
                  </a>
                  
                  
                  <div class="card-block">
                    
                    <h3 class="card-title d-flex align-items-center hidden-sm-down lang-en">
                      Title
                    </h3>
                    Et aliquip non culpa pariatur quis et consectetur dolor eu laborum in nisi voluptate ut commodo dolore dolore anim est et in eu voluptate velit nulla nisi occaecat anim ut.
                    
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
                  
              </div>
                  
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="card-deck">

                <div class="card" data-mh="card">
                
                  <a href="">
                    <img class="card-img-top thumbnail" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/63b7/f/2013/041/9/d/free_youtube_thumbnail_template_by_imaura-d5ugja7.png" alt="Thumbnail" />
                  </a>
                  
                  
                  <div class="card-block">
                    
                    <h3 class="card-title d-flex align-items-center hidden-sm-down lang-en">
                      Title
                    </h3>
                    Et aliquip non culpa pariatur quis et consectetur dolor eu laborum in nisi voluptate ut commodo dolore dolore anim est et in eu voluptate velit nulla nisi occaecat anim ut.
                    
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
                  
              </div>
                  
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="card-deck">

                <div class="card" data-mh="card">
                
                  <a href="">
                    <img class="card-img-top thumbnail" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/63b7/f/2013/041/9/d/free_youtube_thumbnail_template_by_imaura-d5ugja7.png" alt="Thumbnail" />
                  </a>
                  
                  
                  <div class="card-block">
                    
                    <h3 class="card-title d-flex align-items-center hidden-sm-down lang-en">
                      Title
                    </h3>
                    Et aliquip non culpa pariatur quis et consectetur dolor eu laborum in nisi voluptate ut commodo dolore dolore anim est et in eu voluptate velit nulla nisi occaecat anim ut.
                    
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
                  
              </div>
                  
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="card-deck">

                <div class="card" data-mh="card">
                
                  <a href="">
                    <img class="card-img-top thumbnail" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/63b7/f/2013/041/9/d/free_youtube_thumbnail_template_by_imaura-d5ugja7.png" alt="Thumbnail" />
                  </a>
                  
                  
                  <div class="card-block">
                    
                    <h3 class="card-title d-flex align-items-center hidden-sm-down lang-en">
                      Title
                    </h3>
                    Et aliquip non culpa pariatur quis et consectetur dolor eu laborum in nisi voluptate ut commodo dolore dolore anim est et in eu voluptate velit nulla nisi occaecat anim ut.
                    
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
                  
              </div>
                  
            </div>
            
            
            
                
              

              

              

            

            

            

              

              

            

            

          

          </div>

          

         

          

        </section>

          

            

          <section class="col-md-2 hidden-sm-down sidebar">

            <div class="ads">

              Sticky content

            </div>

          </section>

            

          

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="hidden-sm-up">
      <br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
```

However, if the real sticky content takes a while to load, which is very common with Google AdSense and alike, and the user starts scrolling down the page (or press <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, arrows...) when the said slow content finally finishes loading the whole page scrolls to the top.

I've debugged my JS to make sure it wasn't my fault. Also, when I removed the `position: sticky;` declaration jumping stopped.

More important than how could I fix this, I would like to know why this is happening

Comment: Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Right, I see it has partial support  to Chrome 61 and Firefox 56, the versions I have installed but this behaviour isn't listed as "Known issues"

Comment: True, well probably not yet, that's just the result of the current partial support and its usage. We'll still have to wait some time before sticky truly develops.